# PowerShell: Invoke-RestMethod - show percentage progress

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to automate my build and upload process. As part of it, I'm using `Invoke-RestMethod` to upload my file to my API endpoint. This is my command to upload:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadEndpoint -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines -Headers $headers | Out-Null
```

Before invoking this command I'm using `Write-Host` a line without breaking to a new line, and when it's done I'm using `Write-Host` with a line break with "OK", so the output is something like this:

```
Uploading version to server... [OK]
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to get the progress of the file upload from the `Invoke-RestMethod` and while uploading show the progress percentage of the call. Something like:

```
Uploading version to server... 43%
```

Comment: This is what the Write-Progress cmdlet is for. [Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Full]  You must provide the data to calculate how ti will count. What did you search for? What have you tried? What happened when you did? Post your code?  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Even though `Write-Progress` is made for this type of behaviour, I am not aware `Invoke-RestMethod` provides information with which one could calculate the progress.

Answer (score -1):

Theare are 2 way that I know

1. `Write-Progress -Activity "Uploading version to server..." -PercentComplete $perc`
2. `` Write-host "`r"Uploading version to server... $perc" -NoNewline ``

The first method generate a graphical loading bar, the second one is a simple line of text and is more like what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you get the percentage of the progress from `Invoke-RestMethod`?